# silk central parameters through qtp

Tags: qtp, hp-uft, silk-central

I am looking to fetch the results folder from silk central so that I can place my qtp results in the same folder and thereby upload them to silk central. I know that the parameter `#sctm_test_results_dir` can be used in Java with `System.getproperty` and it works if my test is a `Silk4J` test. I have an executable jar file with steps to zip the results and place in the `#sctm_test_results_dir` directory and I call this JAR file from `QTP`. But the value returned for the results dir is `null`. It works fine if I try it as a keyword driven silk4j test though. Any help is appreciated.

The below code is the JAR file which I call from QTP using

```
Systemutil.Run "cmd",""/K "&str01,""
```

... where `str01` is:

```
"cd c:\ "&chr(38)&chr(38)&chr(32)&"java -jar " &chr(34) & JarFilePath & chr(34) & chr(32) & SrcPath
```

JAR file :

```
String Destpath=System.getenv("#sctm_test_results_dir"); 
// ^ returns null 
System.out.println("Sourcepath :"+Sourcepath); 
System.out.println("DestinationPath :"+Destpath); 
zip_pack(Sourcepath,Destpath+"\\test_z001.zip"); 
// ^ function to zip contents 
System.out.println("Zip complete");`
```

Thanks!

Comment: you should add some code example https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: The below code is the JAR file which i call from QTP using Systemutil.Run "cmd",""/K "&str01,"" where str01="cd c:\ "&chr(38)&chr(38)&chr(32)&"java -jar " &chr(34) & JarFilePath & chr(34) & chr(32) & SrcPath

JAR file :                                   
String Destpath=System.getenv("#sctm_test_results_dir"); //returns null     
System.out.println("Sourcepath :"+Sourcepath);
System.out.println("DestinationPath :"+Destpath);
zip_pack(Sourcepath,Destpath+"\\test_z001.zip"); //function to zip contents
System.out.println("Zip complete");

Answer (score 0):

Use a test or execution parameter like `SCResultDir` and give it the value `${#sctm_test_results_dir}`. This will be replaced during execution with the real result directory.

In `QTP/UFT` create a test input parameter with the same name (parameters starting with `#` do not work in UFT).

To use it now in some action just create an action input parameter and assign it to this test parameter in the action call properties.
Then you can use it in this action as parameter for whatever you need it.
Just did it this way and worked fine for me (displayed it in notebook).